# When running php artisan dusk the tests do not complete. They just hang

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

When running `php artisan dusk` the tests do not complete. The process just hangs with no feedback. Sometimes I see `E` for some tests, but no feedback beyond that and full suite of tests has never completed.

I've run `php artisan dusk:chrome-driver` but no change in behavior.

The ChromeDriver binary that is returned with the above "chrome-driver" command completes is: version 114.0.5735.90.

I've also added the following to phpunit.dusk.xml, but that hasn't returned the expected error messaging feedback...

```
<php>
    <ini name="display_errors" value="On" />
    <ini name="display_startup_errors" value="On" />
</php>
```

This is a brand new laptop and I am able to run the testing suite on the previous system without error.

Software and system specs

- Dusk Version: 7.7.1
- Laravel Version: 9.25.0
- PHP Version: 8.1.26
- PHPUnit Version: 9.5.21
- Mac OS Sonoma 14.2.1
- Chip: Apple M3 Pro

Comment: Did you install the dependencies in new system from scratch ? If yes, could you please share the part that you are running your chrome driver ?

Comment: @OnlyMAJ Yes. It's a brand new laptop. I don't exactly understand the question. All my test cases are using `use Laravel\Dusk\Browser`. E.g. `$browser->visit()`.

Comment: @Bob. do a screenshot `$browser->screenshot('filename');` to see if opens browser, and check it on `tests/Browser/screenshots`.

Comment: furthermore, try `php artisan dusk --log-junit junit.log` to see any log and post it if you can

Comment: @francisco It appears the issue is that the latest ChromeDriver for the Google Chrome Mac client is v120 and that's what Dusk is trying to use, but according to the error message I received Dusk only supports v114. 

I tried install v120 `php artisan dusk:chrome-driver 120` but that fails.

Does Dusk need an upgrade? Or should I try to get the older version of Chrome, v114? Finding a legit Google download site to get Chrome v114 is nontrivial, so any advice there would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI, I've got a thread going about this in the Dusk Github: https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/1076

Comment: I've seen, where the `composer require laravel/dusk --with-all-dependencies` updates to latest dusk, you should try in dev.

Comment: the v114 isn't stable on that test?

Comment: @Bob. still show the E without feedback?

Comment: @francisco No. That fixed my issue. I'll mark your note as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `composer require laravel/dusk --with-all-dependencies`, updates the dependencies of packages in the argument list, including those which are root requirements.

The latest current version of Laravel\Dusk is [v7.12.1](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/releases).

Comment: For reference, the fix noted in the CHANGELOG: https://github.com/laravel/dusk/blob/7.x/CHANGELOG.md#v790---2023-07-24